# nginx endless redirection (not the SSL bug)

Tags: php, nginx, opencart, fastcgi

**EDIT: The Problem is, and I can not figure it out exactly is that I use a subdomain, I tried just using my TLD (pure) my.de for the config and voila it worked out of the box. Anyone ideas on how to fix this?**

I am currently using this nginx config to run OpenCart (v1.5.5.1) (PHP) on FastCGI (PHP-FPM) on a nginx 1.3.x on Ubuntu 12.xx (VPS).

When I try to access the index.php in the install folder as described here: http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/Installation I end up in an endless redirection loop:

shop.mysite.com/install/shop.mysite.com/shop.mysite.com/.........etc/index.php

Access log does not show anything helpful and the error log shows nothing.

```
# FORCE WWW
server {
    server_name  .shop.my.de;
    rewrite ^(.*) .shop.my.de$1 permanent;
}
# MAIN SERVER
server {
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/shop.my.de.error.log debug;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/shop.my.de.access.log;
    server_name  .shop.my.de;
    listen 80;
    root /srv/opencart/upload;
    index index.php;

    location /install {
        index index.php;
    }
    location /image/data {
        autoindex on;
    }
    location /admin {
        index index.php;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri @opencart;
    }
    location @opencart {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        #access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        #log_not_found off;
        #access_log off;
    }
    # Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx because nginx would display the source code, and these files can contain PASSWORDS!
    location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
        deny all;
    }
    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        #access_log off;
        #log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        #log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you disable the rewrites and what version of OpenCart are you running?

Comment: Opencart 1.5.5.1, I disabled some of the rewrites (the most top one) does not change. Any other rewrites are critical to ensure OpenCart working.

Comment: Specifically the one with `_route_` I would advise trying. As for the infinite redirect - the install step 1 doesn't have any redirect (neither does the index.php bootstrap so it's not going to be those)

Comment: This behaviour is crazy. I removed every try_files and rewrite statement and it is still showing this behaviour (restarting nginx service after each change to the config).

Comment: What about this line? This seems suspect to be honest

    `location /install {
        index index.php;
    }`

It basically says to use the opencart index.php file instead of /install/index.php - EDIT: Ignore that, I misread the command. I'm unsure then to be honest. I would advise you remove everything that isn't absolutely required, and see if it works - then start adding lines back one at a time

Comment: Already removed it, just had it there for testing. Still does not work. I went over all files again. file ownership and read/write access all correct. PHP-FPM running properly. All files in place etc.

Comment: Very bizarre. One thing is for sure - this is an NGINX issue not an OpenCart one so you're going to need to get an answer from someone with nginx experience (I have none I'm afraid)

Comment: Seems to be an Opencart issue, since creating just an index.php filling it with phpinfo() etc. perfectly works.

Comment: I've probably done over 1000 OpenCart installs on Apache with no issue so not sure how OpenCart is to blame here but possible I guess (some weird bug). However it's not the installer section at least, so it must be a combination of the index.php and the rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is if you want to use NGINX + Opencart on a subdomain:
If you don't do this, opencart will somehow bounce like crazy between redirects.

```
server {
    server_name  .shop.my.de;
    rewrite ^(.*) www.shop.my.de$1 permanent; # the www is the important thing!!
}
```

and

```
server {
    #..........
    server_name  www.shop.my.de; # also HERE! www is the important thing
    #..........
}
```